# Flexbox equal eight 50% width columns not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use Flexbox to make 50% width columns with equal height.  I have this....

```css
.items {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  width:50%;
        margin: 10px;
        background: aqua;
             
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">llamcorper id vehicula quis, sollicitudin a nibh. Quisque sed bibendum ipsum, et tempor arcu. Duis ultrices feugiat purus, ut sollicitudin ipsum interdum a. Nam porta vestibulum elit, et feugiat eros viverra et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam at tempus libero. Donec pretium risus sit amet lacus imperdiet, vitae lacinia lorem eleifend. Mauris faucibus, dolor vel facilisis ultrices, massa urna tempus urna, vitae euismod felis est nd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1sadasdasdasdasd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1satricies fermentum erat luctus placerat. Praesent cursus nisl vitae magna tristique lacinia ac ac justo. Nunc euismod, est sed sodales lacinia, nisi leo luctus nulla, id commodo lectus sem vel erat. Vivamus id quam id ligula condimentum fermentum. Nullam commodo, magna sit amet sdasd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1sadasdasdasdasd
  </div>
</div>
```

It is just displaying in one column, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you use `padding` and `margin` , item's width is equal to 50% + paddings + margins,

As a workaround, you may set a safe `min-width` and set `flex-grow: 1;`

Box-sizing can be reset to include padding in min-width calculation.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  min-width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">llamcorper id vehicula quis, sollicitudin a nibh. Quisque sed bibendum ipsum, et tempor arcu. Duis ultrices feugiat purus, ut sollicitudin ipsum interdum a. Nam porta vestibulum elit, et feugiat eros viverra et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam
    at tempus libero. Donec pretium risus sit amet lacus imperdiet, vitae lacinia lorem eleifend. Mauris faucibus, dolor vel facilisis ultrices, massa urna tempus urna, vitae euismod felis est nd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1sadasdasdasdasd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1satricies fermentum erat luctus placerat. Praesent cursus nisl vitae magna tristique lacinia ac ac justo. Nunc euismod, est sed sodales lacinia, nisi leo luctus nulla, id commodo lectus sem vel erat. Vivamus id quam id ligula condimentum fermentum.
    Nullam commodo, magna sit amet sdasd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1sadasdasdasdasd
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that the width of the box is set to 50%, but that doesn't include padding or margin. You can have the 50% include padding by setting `box-sizing: border-box;` but you can't include the margin. One way to solve this is by using the `flex-grow` attribute, which tells an element how much it can grow to fill empty space in a row (relative to other elements in the row. If all elements have `flex-grow: 1;` they will all grow the same amount).

```css
.items {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: aqua;
             
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">llamcorper id vehicula quis, sollicitudin a nibh. Quisque sed bibendum ipsum, et tempor arcu. Duis ultrices feugiat purus, ut sollicitudin ipsum interdum a. Nam porta vestibulum elit, et feugiat eros viverra et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam at tempus libero. Donec pretium risus sit amet lacus imperdiet, vitae lacinia lorem eleifend. Mauris faucibus, dolor vel facilisis ultrices, massa urna tempus urna, vitae euismod felis est nd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1sadasdasdasdasd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1satricies fermentum erat luctus placerat. Praesent cursus nisl vitae magna tristique lacinia ac ac justo. Nunc euismod, est sed sodales lacinia, nisi leo luctus nulla, id commodo lectus sem vel erat. Vivamus id quam id ligula condimentum fermentum. Nullam commodo, magna sit amet sdasd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 1sadasdasdasdasd
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have `padding` and `margin`, it adds to your `width: 50%` of your `.item`, to compensate padding you should add `box-sizing: border-box`, and to compensate margins you can wrap `.item` content to one more div.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div>llamcorper id vehicula quis, sollicitudin a nibh. Quisque sed bibendum ipsum, et tempor arcu. Duis ultrices feugiat purus, ut sollicitudin ipsum interdum a. Nam porta vestibulum elit, et feugiat eros viverra et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam
      at tempus libero. Donec pretium risus sit amet lacus imperdiet, vitae lacinia lorem eleifend. Mauris faucibus, dolor vel facilisis ultrices, massa urna tempus urna, vitae euismod felis est nd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 1sadasdasdasdasd</div>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 1satricies fermentum erat luctus placerat. Praesent cursus nisl vitae magna tristique lacinia ac ac justo. Nunc euismod, est sed sodales lacinia, nisi leo luctus nulla, id commodo lectus sem vel erat. Vivamus id quam id ligula condimentum fermentum.
      Nullam commodo, magna sit amet sdasd</div>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div> Item 1sadasdasdasdasd</div>

  </div>
</div>
```